# Map marker is not rendering using Mapbox GL JS

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, react-mapbox-gl

I am trying to render markers using Mapbox GL JS in a React / Next application. The map is rendering, but the markers are not. Here is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Container, Box, Button } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import mapboxgl from "mapbox-gl";
mapboxgl.accessToken = [ACCESS TOKEN];
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const MapContainer = styled(Box)`
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;

  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const MainContainer = styled(Container)({
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'row'
});

export default function Home() {
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: mapContainer.current,
      style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
      center: [-74.0060, 40.7128], // Starting position [lng, lat]
      zoom: 12,
    });

    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), "top-right");

    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';
    el.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://placekitten.com/g/500)';
    el.style.width = '100px';
    el.style.height = '100px';

    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
    .setLngLat([-74.0060, 40.7128]) // Marker position [lng, lat]
    .addTo(map);

    // Clean up on unmount
    return () => {
      map.remove();
    };
  });

  return (
    <MainContainer disableGutters maxWidth={false}>
      <MapContainer ref={mapContainer} />
    </MainContainer>
  );
}
```

Fwiw, the navigation control placed in the top right also doesn't appear, so it doesn't seem to be a marker-specific issue. Maybe it has to do with how I am rendering the map in the useEffect. Please advise :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the stylesheet!

```
import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'
```